# Copy styles to other class in SCSS without @extend?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to create a helper mixin in my SCSS file for easily styling form input placeholder texts. For a while, I only needed to change the text's color, so I had this mixin:

```
@mixin input-placeholder($color, $opacity, $focusColor: null, $focusOpacity: null) {
    &:-moz-placeholder {
        color: $color;
        opacity: $opacity;
    }
    &::-moz-placeholder {
        color: $color;
        opacity: $opacity;
    }
    &:-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: $color;
        opacity: $opacity;
    }
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: $color;
        opacity: $opacity;
    }
    &:placeholder {
        color: $color;
        opacity: $opacity;
    }
    &:invalid {
        color: $color;
    }
    &:focus {
        @if($focusColor==null) {
            $focusColor: transparent;
        }
        @if($focusOpacity==null) {
            $focusOpacity: 0;
        }
        &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            color: $focusColor !important;
            opacity: $focusOpacity !important;
        }
        &:-moz-placeholder {
            color: $focusColor !important;
            opacity: $focusOpacity !important;
        }
        &::-moz-placeholder {
            color: $focusColor !important;
            opacity: $focusOpacity !important;
        }
        &:-ms-input-placeholder {
            color: $focusColor !important;
            opacity: $focusOpacity !important;
        }
        &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            color: $focusColor !important;
            opacity: $focusOpacity !important;
        }
        &:placeholder {
            color: $focusColor !important;
            opacity: $focusOpacity !important;
        }
    }
}
```

This purposely adds each selector separately and not in a comma separated list due to the fact that [some browsers will ignore the entire entry if one is invalid](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#Conformance).

I wanted to use @extend so that I could create a mixin like this:

```
@mixin style-input-placeholder($module) {
    &:-moz-placeholder {
        @extend #{$module};
    }
    &::-moz-placeholder {
        @extend #{$module};
    }
    &:-ms-input-placeholder {
        @extend #{$module};
    }
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        @extend #{$module};
    }
    &:placeholder {
        @extend #{$module};
    }
    &:invalid {
        @extend #{$module};
    }
}
```

Where $module is the selector I pass to the mixin to extend the styles of, and I'd be able to use it like this:

```
.some-special-placeholder-styles {
    color: purple;
    opacity: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
input {
    @include style-input-placeholder('.some-special-placeholder-styles');
}
```

It would allow me to modify more than just the color and opacity without having to annoyingly specify each attribute as a mixin parameter. But because of the nature of @extend, it combines all of those selectors into one comma separated list. So is there something else I can do or any workarounds that you've come across?

Comment: hm, just from the top of my head: maybe you could put your selectors in arrays (maps) and iterate over those with @each, then add the code inside? I am not sure though if that would put it on individual lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [@content](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Passing_Content_Blocks_to_a_Mixin__mixin-content) directive to pass arbitrary content inside mixins (was added into sass 3.2). So your code may look like:

```
@mixin style-input-placeholder() {
    &:-moz-placeholder {
        @content;
    }
    &::-moz-placeholder {
        @content;
    }
    &:-ms-input-placeholder {
        @content;
    }
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        @content;
    }
    &:placeholder {
        @content;
    }
    &:invalid {
        @content;
    }
}

input {
    @include style-input-placeholder() {
        color: purple;
        opacity: 0;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    }
}
```

Also you can try to wire your sass compilation with [PostCSS](http://postcss.org/) and use excellent [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) plugin that will free you from defining all these vendor-specific prefixes.

Comment: This sounds perfect! I'll try it when I'm back on the project. Thank you!

Comment: @Tessa please mark answer as accepted when you'll try it out in a case if it resolves your problem so people with similar questions will be able to find answer faster.